# Colocar imagen del storage de firebase en el nav_header del navegation_drawer

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Buenas tengo `NavegationDrawer` que tiene una imagen en el `nav_header`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quisiera saber como puedo reemplazar esa imagen por la imagen que esta en el `storage` de `firebase` de un usuario

eh intentado colocar esto en el `activity` de mi `navegation drawer` pero se detiene la aplicación

```
public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private ImageView imgperfil;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference alumnos;
private StorageReference mStorage;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    imgperfil = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgperfil);
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    final FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_menu, new InicioFragment()).commit();

----------------------------A partir de aqui--------------------

    mAuthListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                alumnos = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Alumnos");
                alumnos.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String imageUrl=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Foto_Perfil").getValue());
                        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageUrl)){
                            Picasso.with(MenuActivity.this).load(Uri.parse(imageUrl)).into(imgperfil);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }else {
                startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, IniciaSesionActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
-------------------------Hasta aquí----------------------------------
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
            mAuth.signOut();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_menu, new InicioFragment()).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Inicio");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_menu, new PerfilFragment()).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Perfil");

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_menu, new AcercadeFragment()).commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Acerca de");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Me aparece el siguiente error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                               Process: com.juegosludicos.juegosludicosmejoradodos, PID: 26993
                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                                                                                            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
                                                                                            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                                                                                            at com.juegosludicos.juegosludicosmejoradodos.MenuActivity$1$1.onDataChange(MenuActivity.java:89)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Al parecer estoy llamando mal en la parte de

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String imageUrl=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Foto_Perfil").getValue());
                        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageUrl)){
                            //Glide.with(Main3Activity.this).load(Uri.parse(imageUrl)).into(imgperfil);
-----------A esta linea marca el error----------------
                            Picasso.with(MenuActivity.this).load(Uri.parse(imageUrl)).into(imgperfil);
--------------------------------------------
                        }
                    }
```

dentro de mi `mAuthListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {...}`

Answer (score 1):

A primera vista se ve que no esta encontrando el ID `imgperfil` en el layout de tu activity, lo cual es lógico ya que seguramente esa imagen esta definida en un xml distinto.

Para poder acceder a ese imageview vas a tener que acceder al layout inflado del navigation drawer y llamar findViewById sobre ESE layout.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo que intentaste usar `Glide` y que ahora lo tienes comentado, has dado un paso atrás en tu intento, quizá porque no implementaste bien esa herramienta, que es la recomendada actualmente para hacer lo que quieres.

Observa lo que dice la documentación:

### Descarga imágenes con FirebaseUI

> [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) proporciona vínculos nativos simples, personalizables
>   y listos para la producción con el objetivo de eliminar el código
>   estándar y **promover las prácticas recomendadas de Google**. Con
>   FirebaseUI, puedes descargar, almacenar en caché y mostrar imágenes
>   con rapidez y facilidad desde Cloud Storage, gracias a nuestra
>   integración con [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).
>
> <sub>Documentación de Firebase: [Cómo descargar archivos en Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=es-419).</sub>

Empecemos de nuevo:

1. Si no lo has hecho, agrega FirebaseUI a tu `app/build.gradle`:

   ```
   dependencies {
       // FirebaseUI Storage only
       compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
   }
   ```
2. Luego, puedes cargar imágenes directamente desde Storage a una `ImageView`:
   Aquí:

   - deberás sustituir `imageView` por `imgperfil`que es, supongo el del perfil.
   - en el contexto puedes dejar `this`, si no funciona, prueba a poner entonces `MenuActivity.this` en su lugar.
   - el `storageReference` debes obtenerlo como explica firebase en la documentación, en el apartado [*Crear una referencia*](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?hl=es-419). Lo digo porque, en el código comentado, intentabas obtener la imagen parseando una URL. En Firebase, cuando creas una referencia, estás dentro, no tienes que parsear nada, simplemente usar el recurso. Lo que debes cuidar es de crear adecuadamente la referencia.

     ```
     // Lo ESENCIAL es que hagas referencia correctamente a tu imagen
     StorageReference storageReference = ...;

     // Este sería el imageView de tu Activity
     ImageView imageView = ...;

     // Ahora sólo llamas tu imagen con Glide
     Glide.with(this /* context */)
             .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
             .load(storageReference)
             .into(imageView);
     ```